# Artificial Bee Colony library

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, artificial-intelligence

I'm working on the implementation of [Artificial Bee Colony algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_Bee_Colony_Algorithm) in optimization of fuzzy c-means clustering. Can anyone provide a link for C# library or class that might help in the code of the ABC algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google doesn't immediately seem to reveal a C# implementation of the ABC algorithm, though there is [a Java implementation](http://mf.erciyes.edu.tr/abc/software.htm) which should translate quite well to C#.

Answer (score 4):

I think [**this**](https://github.com/abhishekcghosh/ABC-Algorithm-Library) should help. Its a ready to implement ABC algorithm library written in C++ that I had developed.

Comment: To people who say "this is not an answer": when the question asks for a link, I think providing a link is a pretty valid answer. Having said that, the who question has been put on hold as being off-topic for asking for a library. So it is a "good answer to a bad question".

Answer (score 0):

ABC souds similar to ant colony optimisation. I found [this app](http://www.nightlab.ch/antsim.php), which you can probably get the source for if you contact the authors. It requires .NET, so it might as well be written in C#. It's not exactly what you asked for, but it's something ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a recent [**article in MSDN magazine**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg983491.aspx) that has an implementation in C#, on a specific problem. It should provide a good starting point!